# Can't launch gnome-terminal from anacron job

Tags: gnome-terminal, cron-jobs

A few releases ago (lucid lynx) I wrote a backup shell script task that was executed as an anacron job every week. It worked fine then. However, It fails in natty.

The idea was simple. The script referenced by the anacron job just launched gnome-terminal with the actual backup script passed in as the argument. So a new terminal window popped up showing the script output.

Here you are my anacron file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/673965/
and here, the launcher: http://paste.ubuntu.com/673963/

Any idea about why what once worked, stopped working? And more important, what to do to make it work again?

Note: I would appreciate tested solutions when possible...

Comment: Do you have some errors to show? What if you run the launcher from a virtual terminal, say tty1?

Comment: I'll show them tomorrow, but I think it has to do with my DISPLAY variable setting...though it worked on lucid

Comment: You should not launch graphical applications (gnome-terminal) from a cron job, cron jobs are used for batch (non interactive) tasks.

Comment: The thing is that I want the user to be aware of the execution of the backup job, and want her to see the task ouput while it is being executed. How would you do that?

Comment: For that you should use some GUI alarm application which allows to execute commands.

Comment: No need to use a GUI app just to show the user the output of a bash shell script. I still think using anacron is a good solution, as cron was created to execute scheduled commands, not only batch tasks. By the way, here are my errors: http://paste.ubuntu.com/675366/

Comment: What is the log output from anacron?? I think the standard is that the log is send to the root user account.

Comment: If you wanted users to be able to watch the output, then perhaps you could run the script in a screen session?

Comment: Source Lab, I redirected stderr to stdout, and you can see the output here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/675366

Comment: Jo-Erlend Schinstad, how should I do that?

Comment: @zuzust - are you using a root cron entry or a user cron entry?  The third solution given works just fine on my computer if its a user cron entry

Comment: @fossfreedom - I'm using anacron, so it is being executed as root, and it is as it should be, I mean, it is mandatory that the backup script is executed as root

Comment: Remember I'm using Ubuntu Natty. As I mentioned above it stopped working in this release, but it worked fine in lucid lynx.

Answer (score 2):

**Third**
You could call the gnome-terminal directly from anacron file, something like:

```
7 5 * * * env DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal -e "/home/carles/Admin/dotfiles/bin/jobs/backup/backup-reisender"
```

**Second**
Maybe we could try this "cheat":

```
bash -c "gnome-terminal -e '/home/carles/Admin/dotfiles/bin/jobs/backup/backup-reisender 0'"
```

**First**
Once I could fix a similar problem by changing this:

```
gnome-terminal --command="/home/carles/Admin/dotfiles/bin/jobs/backup/backup-reisender 0"
```

into this:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"/home/carles/Admin/dotfiles/bin/jobs/backup/backup-reisender 0; exec bash\""
```

Comment: What was the issue you had to fix? And, what's the reason for exec bash? Notice that backup-reisender is a bash shell script. Thanks in advance..

Comment: The issue was a shortcut key combination that refuses to work unless I made the changes above. The "exec bash" was required also for the issue I had. This suggestion didn't work for you?

Comment: Nop, it didn't work :( The issue has more to do with launching a GUI app like gnome-terminal...

Comment: May be we could try the other way around? I've updated the answer.

Comment: Maybe calling the graphical environment from anacron as suggested here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#GUI_Applications

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your solution and tomorrow I'll tell you if it works.

Comment: Same output, it didn't work :(

Comment: How sad is it :'-(